# x3dom artefact rendering

Tags: html, x3dom

I'm just discovering X3DOM and playing with it.
I have draw a chair with sketchup and converted to x3d with meshlab.
I'm using the "html5" syntax to write my page. Depending on "something" I have diferent rendering and I don't know what.

Rendering I consider ok: http://aws.ysagon.com/x3d/x3dom/ok.html

Rendering I consider not ok: http://aws.ysagon.com/x3d/x3dom/bad.html

What bother me is that the one I consider ok is the one with html error (the tag `<Coordinate>` is self closed and should not). In the bad example, the tag is not self closed.

Can someone please explain me why it seems to have two rendering mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out what was the problem. When there is a syntax error in my html file, the `<Normal vector" ...">` isn't used and in my case without this vector the rendering appears better. I now have to figure why!

edit:

The normal vector was "wrong" (at least for x3dom). Generating a correct normal vector along with the object did the trick. So it seems it's better to have no normal than a "bad" normal.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 doesn't work too well with X3DOM, in fact, X3DOM is the result of JavaScript and HTML talking the Shockwave Flash syntax. I have no clue how you got it to work with HTML5, but flash is recommended.

Okay, I have some solutions that might or might not work.

1.Get into the X3D file with a text application. (Any, TextWrangler is recommended)

2.Use another 3D modeling program. (Blender works fine, so I recommend it)

3.Does the object have a big file size?... (BIG as in over ~50 MB) because X3DOM is trying to do whatever it can to render the object file.

Comment: of course it's working fine with html5! As far as I know, the flash player is only here for fallback. Where did you see it's recommended? Any way, the rendering was similar with flash and html5.